# How can we retrieve all possible routing paths from the trace file in NS2?

Tags: path, routes

I want to find all possible routing paths from source to destination in  manet using AODV routing protocol.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. Write more, explain 1) what you want 2) what you tried 3) why it didn't work. And do it in clear, round sentences.

Comment: How can we retrieve all possible routing paths from the trace file in ns2?

Comment: Not here. Edit it into the question, you see the "edit" link. You can always edit your own question. The formalities are important on the StackOverflow. And detail your problem more, questions below 3-4 sentences are mostly not enough clear. I understand it looks hairsplitting, but note: this is exactly why you've found us with the google here.